# Is the repeated G-test of goodness-of-fit the appropriate statistical analysis?

Tags: repeated-measures, goodness-of-fit, biostatistics

I made observations of animal social behavior in which I categorized interactions as either competitive, cooperative, or neutral (i.e. one nominal variable with three possible outcomes). I want to test if the outcome counts are significantly different from the expectation that all three outcomes are equally likely, or in other words, are interactions primarily competitive, cooperative, or neutral, or is there no primary interaction type?

Initially, I thought of the exact multinomial test, but since I have multiple measurements from each interacting pair, my data do not meet the assumption of independence. Then, I investigated the repeated G-test of goodness-of-fit [http://www.biostathandbook.com/repgtestgof.html] as a possibility. This resource does not explain the assumptions of the test, but since this method runs multiple g-tests for each group (in this case, pairs) and the g-test of goodness-of-fit assumes independence between observations, it does not seem that this is the appropriate test either.

1. Am I correct that the repeated G-test of goodness-of-fit assumes independence between observations and that this is not the appropriate test for my data set?
2. Given dependence between observations, is there a more appropriate test that will answer if there is a primary interaction type, especially considering that there is only one nominal variable?

Comment: Why do you want a test? And, what is the hypothesis (formulated with a formula?) You would be better off estimating some model. If you take the outcomes as ordered (say, cooperative < neutral < competitive) you could try some ordinal multinomial regression, with some random effects to account for dependence. From such a model you could get confidence intervals for the parameters. What is your sample size? Range of observations for each pair? Do some animals participate in different pairs?

Comment: Thank you for your response to my question! I hope the following adequately addresses your questions. 1) Why do you want a test? I want to test this data set to see if social interactions are characteristically one type or another. Can we use these data to make predictions about how animals interact in social situations? 2) And, what is the hypothesis (formulated with a formula?)  I apologize as I do not have a formula, but the null hypothesis is that pairs are mostly competitive with the alternative hypothesis that pairs are mostly cooperative.

Comment: 3) What is your sample size? I am unsure about my sample size because I have video observations, and I have yet to score all of the videos. I estimate a sample of approximately 500 observations. 4) Range of observations for each pair? Again, I am unsure about range of observations for the pairs, but I have twenty individuals spread across five groups. 5) Do some animals participate in different pairs? All individuals within a group participate in each pairing, but they do not participate across groups. I hope this is enough information. If you need clarification, please let me know.